# Body Onload Only Loads First Condition

Tags: javascript, php, onload

I am trying to execute one or both scripts in the body onload event that pulls data from a mysql database, but when I test, the first if statement is the only one that runs. I know I'm probably just structuring the if statement wrong, but can't figure out what I'm missing. The two fields in question are checkboxes with values "Y" or "":

```
<body 
    <?php if($casedetail['field1']==='Y') if($casedetail['field2']==='Y') {echo 'onload= "showCS(); showWC()"';}
    else if($casedetail['field1']==='Y') if($casedetail['field2']==='') {echo 'onload= "showCS()"';}
    else if($casedetail['field1']==='')  if($casedetail['field2']==='Y') {echo 'onload= "showWC()"';} ?> >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, to check multiple conditions use `&&` and operator

```
<?php 
if(($casedetail['field1']=='Y') && ($casedetail['field2']=='Y')) {
    echo 'onload= "showCS(); showWC()"';
}else if(($casedetail['field1']=='Y') && ($casedetail['field2']=='')) {
    echo 'onload= "showCS()"';
}else if(($casedetail['field1']=='') && ($casedetail['field2']=='Y')) {
    echo 'onload= "showWC()"';
} ?>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you It looks like you had a couple dollar signs where the ampersands should be in the middle condition, but I understood what you meant!  You're awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Oops, typo. Fixed, plus added brackets for clarity